# Binary Operator '>= & <=' cannot be applied to operands of type CGFloat and Int In Swift

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, int, cgfloat, binary-operators

I'm getting two errors. When I use the <= and >=, it gives me the errors:

Binary Operator '>= & <=' cannot be applied to operands of type CGFloat and Int

```
 override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    var speedOfTouch = 30

    for touch: AnyObject in touches {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)

        if location.x < CGRectGetMidX(self.frame) {
            square.position.x <= speedOfTouch
            square.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: -40, dy: 0))



        }
        else {
            square.position.x >= speedOfTouch
            square.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: 40, dy: 0))
        }

    }
}
```

I need help!

Answer (score 0):

Change one line:

```
let speedOfTouch = CGFLoat(30)
```

It didn't work because you can't compare two different types as the compiler states

Answer (score 0):

The swift complier considers it a programmer's error to try and compare two different types.

Just change your code to:

```
var speedOfTouch = 30 as CGFloat
```

Answer (score 0):

I see at least two problems.

1. `speedOfTouch` has type `Int` because you didn't specify any other type. So in the expression `square.position.x <= speedOfTouch`, you're trying to compare a `CGFloat` and an `Int`.

   Swift doesn't automatically convert between numeric types, and doesn't define a `<=` operator that takes a `CGFloat` on the left and an `Int` on the right, so you cannot compare two values of different types.

   You can fix this by, for example, explicitly declaring `speedOfTouch` as `CGFloat`:

   ```
   var speedOfTouch: CGFloat = 30
   ```
2. The other problem, which will not give you a compiler error, is that you have written `square.position.x <= speedOfTouch` as a statement. You are comparing two values, but you're not doing anything with the outcome of the comparison.

   In an optimized (release) build, the compiler will probably eliminate the comparison entirely. So why are you doing it?

   You probably wanted to do something with the outcome of the comparison. Maybe, for example, you wanted to do this:

   ```
   if ((location.x < CGRectGetMidX(self.frame))
       && (square.position.x <= speedOfTouch)) {
       square.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: -40, dy: 0))
   }
   ```